# can I send “SMS received intent” in android 4.1.2?

Tags: android, sms

This code doesn't work with android version 4.1.2,

```
private static void createFakeSms(Context context, String sender,String body) 
{
  byte[] pdu = null;
  byte[] scBytes = PhoneNumberUtils.networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD("0000000000");
  byte[] senderBytes = PhoneNumberUtils.networkPortionToCalledPartyBCD(sender);
  int lsmcs = scBytes.length;
  byte[] dateBytes = new byte[7];
  Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
  dateBytes[0] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
  dateBytes[1] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
  dateBytes[2] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
  dateBytes[3] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)));
  dateBytes[4] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
  dateBytes[5] = reverseByte((byte) (calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
  dateBytes[6] = reverseByte((byte) ((calendar.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) + calendar
 .get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)) / (60 * 1000 * 15)));
  try 
  {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bo.write(lsmcs);
    bo.write(scBytes);
    bo.write(0x04);
    bo.write((byte) sender.length());
    bo.write(senderBytes);
    bo.write(0x00);
    bo.write(0x00); // encoding: 0 for default 7bit
    bo.write(dateBytes);
    try 
    {
      String sReflectedClassName = "com.android.internal.telephony.GsmAlphabet";
      Class cReflectedNFCExtras = Class.forName(sReflectedClassName);
      Method stringToGsm7BitPacked = cReflectedNFCExtras.getMethod(
      "stringToGsm7BitPacked", new Class[] { String.class });
      stringToGsm7BitPacked.setAccessible(true);
      byte[] bodybytes = (byte[]) stringToGsm7BitPacked.invoke(null,body);
      bo.write(bodybytes);
     } 
     catch (Exception e) 
     {
     }
     pdu = bo.toByteArray();
     }  
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
     }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
            "com.android.mms.transaction.SmsReceiverService");
    intent.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    intent.putExtra("pdus", new Object[] { pdu });
    intent.putExtra("format", "3gpp");
    context.startService(intent);
}

private static byte reverseByte(byte b) {
    return (byte) ((b & 0xF0) >> 4 | (b & 0x0F) << 4);
}
```

When I call `context.startService(intent)` I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED cmp=com.android.mms/.transaction.SmsReceiverService (has extras) } without permission not exported from uid 10046**
```

on virtual device 4.1.2 it works perfectly but not in my GS2 device.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer versions of Android this is a protected broadcast which can only be sent by system apps for security reasons.

The only way to get your app to send it is to convince the OEM to make it a system app on their ROM

Comment: THANKS!! Now i call Android OEM and i try to convince them. :-)